# Correct sensor readings not written to database

Tags: python, arduino

I have an Arduino MKR1000 set up with a light sensor that basically provides a boolean value based on whether it's light or dark.

```
{
  pinMode(6, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  bool gotLight = (digitalRead(6) == LOW);
  String PostDataTrue = "TRUE";
  String PostDataFalse = "FALSE";

  if (gotLight == 1) {
  Serial.println(PostDataTrue);
  delay(1000); 
  }

  if (gotLight == 0) {
  Serial.println(PostDataFalse);
  delay(1000); 
  }

}
```

When I run the serial monitor, I can see that it is correctly giving readings that alternate based on whether or not I am exposing the sensor to light.

However, the python script I am using to write these values to a Postgres DB seems to get "stuck" on certain values.  For example, while the serial monitor might ready TRUE, FALSE, TRUE if I cover and uncover the sensor.  What ends up in the table would be TRUE, TRUE, TRUE.

The values that end up in the table do vary between TRUE and FALSE, but usually what happens is, it starts reading TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, etc. until I cover the sensor, then it will correctly read FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, etc., but when I uncover the sensor, it will still be inserting FALSE into the table.

I'm posting my python code below.  Would be grateful if someone could point me to what's causing this.

```
import serial
import psycopg2
import datetime
import time

# Initiate the serial connection to the Arduino device.
try:
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbmodem14401', 115200, timeout=1)
    # Brief pause to establish connection to port.
    time.sleep(3)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    exit(1)

def insert_data(dt, s1):
    '''Insert data into the database.'''
    conn = psycopg2.connect('''
                            [my connection string info here]
                            ''')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('''INSERT INTO lightbool
                (date_time, sensor1)
                VALUES (%s, %s)''', (dt, s1))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


def read_sensors():
    '''Read the sensors connected to Arduino device.'''
    global sensor1
    # When the Arduino receives the character 'z' it will read the sensor data.
    ser.write(b'z')
    try:
        data = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
        data = data.split()
        sensor1 = data[0]
        print("{} {} {}".format(sensor1))
        return (sensor1)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return


while True:
    # Get the current date and time from the datetime module.
    time_now = datetime.datetime.today()
    date_time = datetime.datetime.strftime(time_now, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    read_sensors()
    print(date_time, sensor1)
    # Save data in a Postgresql database.
    insert_data(date_time, sensor1)
    # Pause a few seconds.
    time.sleep(3)


ser.close()
```

Comment: I would get rid of your use of ```global sensor1```. You are returning the value of sensor1 so why use a global variable? In your main loop use ```sensor1=read_sensor()```.

Comment: @SixenseMan - which is the main loop? the `try:` at the top with my serial info? or the `while True:`?

Comment: I was referring to the ```while True```

Comment: @SixenseMan - I added that line to the loop, but I am getting this output over and over:
```
Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple
Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple
2020-02-18 13:41:33 None
```

Comment: If ```sensor1``` is a string, then ```print('{} {} {}'.format(sensor1))``` will cause an ```IndexError```

Comment: @SixenseMan - ah yes there were 2 too many `{}`s in that `print`.  I removed them.  Also changed `sensor1=read_sensor()` to `data = ser.readline().decode('utf-8') /
    data = data.split() /
    sensor1 = data[0]` It's now producing the correct values.  But the inserts are happening out of order in the table.  E.g. it will insert one row into the middle of the table, and the next one to the end of the table.  (I can tell bc the time stamps are out of order.) Do you know why this would happen?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208081/discussion-between-reallymemorable-and-sixenseman).